# How to view a laravel module?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a modular laravel proyect that someone else created, for what I can see they used nWidart/laravel-modules for modules creation, however I dont know how O can see if the module was created correctly when I test it on the browser What URL should I use?

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => 'prueba1', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Prueba1\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'Prueba1Controller@index');
});
```

that is the route created with the module

Comment: domain.com/prueba1/

Comment: Thank you I had already tried that but it was not working because of an error in json but its al fixed now

Answer (score 0):

`yourdomain/prueba1`

And make sure your **'Prueba1Controller@index'** controller method working fine. For testing purpose you can dump something in your controller method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any unique url to test that in browser. According to your route and prefix you should be able to browse like `http://your-server/prueba1`

If that won't work then you can try another package which one is easier to create module as well as remove. Below is the quite nice simple package that I have used for my project too. You can try this I hope you'll love this.

```
composer require yubarajshrestha/ym
```

Add the service provider to config/app.php

```
YubarajShrestha\YM\YMServiceProvider::class,
```

```
YubarajShrestha\YM\YMModuleProvider::class,
```

Add following line after `"App\": "app/"` in composer.json

**"YModules\": "YModules/"**

Example:

`"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "YModules\\": "YModules/"
}`

`php artisan vendor:publish`

`php artisan migrate`

`composer dump-autoload -o`

You're now good to go on...

For More visit:

[Laravel Module](https://github.com/yubarajshrestha/laravel-module)